# Adding Google Maps "My Maps" feature to own website? - import .kml files

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web

I am looking to add the Google Map API to my own website, but I would like to also include the "My Maps" feature which allows a user to import a .gpx, or .kml file and display the data on the map.

Obviously it is possible to add just a standard interactive Google Map to a website but is the import function possible?

Comment: Are you sure about the `google-app-engine` tag? I don't see how it fits in.

Comment: I removed the app-engine tag. It's definitely not applicable to the question.

Comment: Well, sorry. Do you happen to have an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GGeoXml will let you easily add a KML or GeoRSS file to your map (assuming that file is publicly accessible at some URL)

Docs: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GGeoXml
Sample: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/ggeoxml_loader2.html